# "named" BibTex style and others fail

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to get the `jneurosci` style to work with `bibtex`. This style is closely related to to the `named` style and both of these fail. They produce `.bbl` files which generate `undefined control sequence` errors. I can't see what I'm doing wrong. My `.bib` file works fine with other styles, such as `apalike` or `plain`. Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

I compile as follows:

```
latex myFile
bibtex myFile
latex myFile
latex myFile
```

With the `named` style I get this error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \protect \citeauthoryear 
                                    {Akalal \bgroup \em et al.\egroup }{2010}
l.4   }{2010}]{Akalal2010}
```

The `.bbl` which fails looks like this:

```
\bibitem[\protect\citeauthoryear{Akalal \bgroup \em et al.\egroup
  }{2010}]{Akalal2010}
David-Benjamin~G Akalal, Dinghui Yu, and Ronald~L Davis.
\newblock {A late-phase, long-term memory trace forms in the $\gamma$ neurons
  of Drosophila mushroom bodies after olfactory classical conditioning.}
\newblock {\em The Journal of neuroscience : the official journal of the
  Society for Neuroscience}, 30(49):16699--708, December 2010.
```

When I use the `plain` style (which compiles fine) I get a `.bbl` that looks like this:

```
\bibitem{Akalal2010}
David-Benjamin~G Akalal, Dinghui Yu, and Ronald~L Davis.
\newblock {A late-phase, long-term memory trace forms in the $\gamma$ neurons
  of Drosophila mushroom bodies after olfactory classical conditioning.}
\newblock {\em The Journal of neuroscience : the official journal of the
  Society for Neuroscience}, 30(49):16699--708, December 2010.
```

My `.bib` file looks like this:

```
@article{Agarwal2011,
abstract = {Insect pheromonal glomeruli are thought to track the fine spatiotemporal features of one or a few odorants to aid conspecific localization. However, it is not clear whether they function differently from generalist glomeruli, which respond to many odorants. In this study, we test how DA1, a model pheromonal glomerulus in the fruit fly, represents the spatial and temporal properties of its input, compared with other glomeruli. We combine calcium imaging and electrical stimulation in an isolated brain preparation for a simultaneous, unbiased comparison of the functional organization of many glomeruli. In contrast to what is found in other glomeruli, we find that ipsilateral and contralateral stimuli elicit distinct spatial patterns of activity within DA1. DA1's output shows a greater preference for ipsilateral stimuli in males than in females. DA1 experiences greater and more rapid inhibition than other glomeruli, allowing it to report slight interantennal delays in stimulus onset in a "winner-take-all" manner. DA1's ability to encode spatiotemporal input features distinguishes it from other glomeruli in the fruit fly antennal lobe but relates it to pheromonal glomeruli in other insect species. We propose that DA1 is specialized to help the fly localize and orient with respect to pheromone sources.},
author = {Agarwal, Gautam and Isacoff, Ehud},
doi = {10.1152/jn.00591.2010},
issn = {1522-1598},
journal = {Journal of neurophysiology},
keywords = {Animals,Behavior, Animal,Behavior, Animal: physiology,Calcium,Calcium: metabolism,Drosophila,Drosophila: physiology,Electric Stimulation,Female,Male,Odors,Olfactory Pathways,Olfactory Pathways: physiology,Sex Attractants,Sex Attractants: physiology},
month = apr,
number = {4},
pages = {1711--21},
pmid = {21289134},
title = {{Specializations of a pheromonal glomerulus in the Drosophila olfactory system.}},
url = {http://jn.physiology.org/cgi/content/abstract/105/4/1711},
volume = {105},
year = {2011}
}
```

Comment: I think you need to include `\usepackage{jneurosci}`. Some commands generated during the bibliography extraction process are defined in there.

Comment: Ah! Thanks, guys! I didn't know I needed to load a jneurosci package. It works now.

Comment: @R.Campbell: I converted my comment to a proper answer. Glad to hear it works now. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

The `jneurosci` bibliography style makes use of some commands - for example, `\citeauthoryear` - defined in a package of the same name. In order to make that specific style work, we need to add the following package inclusion

```
\usepackage{jneurosci}
```

in the preamble of our document:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Agarwal2011,
    author = {Agarwal, Gautam and Isacoff, Ehud},
    doi = {10.1152/jn.00591.2010},
    issn = {1522-1598},
    journal = {Journal of neurophysiology},
    month = apr,
    number = {4},
    pages = {1711--21},
    pmid = {21289134},
    title = {Specializations of a pheromonal glomerulus in the Drosophila olfactory system.},
    url = {http://jn.physiology.org/cgi/content/abstract/105/4/1711},
    volume = {105},
    year = {2011}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{jneurosci}


\begin{document}

Hello~\cite{Agarwal2011}.

\bibliographystyle{jneurosci}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

And we get the correct output:

[image: Quack!]

Hope it helps. `:)`